# Does SharePoint 2016 support SQL Server 2014 SP2?

Tags: sql-server, 2016, sql-server-2014

In official requirements the supported versions of SQL Server are 2014 SP1 and 2016. It is not clear are 2014 SP2 and 2016 SP1 supported?

I need to set up devtest 3-tier farm for SharePoint 2016.
I already have one dedicated machine with SQL Server 2014, which way should I go - update it to SP1 or SP2 or reinstall 2016 or 2016 SP1?

Also I need to set up single server dev env for SharePoint 2016.
I have already installed SQL Server 2014 SP2, but not started with SP2016. Should I continue with SP or reinstall SQL Server 2014 SP1?

Answer (score 1):

**[Does SharePoint 2016 support SQL Server 2014 SP2?](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/)**

As a short answer Yes, you can install SharePoint 2016 with

- SQL Server 2014 SP2.
- SQL Server 2016 SP1.

> For more details, please check **[Supported SQL Server Version for SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-2016-sp1-support-sharepoint-2016/)**

---

In [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973), SharePoint 2016 supports

- The 64-bit edition of Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
- Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RTM.

Actually, this is the **Minimum** baseline requirements for a database server on a farm. so any current and future SPs should be supported.

> Check also
>
> - [**Supported SQL Server Versions for SharePoint 2019**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-best-practices-sharepoint/#Supported-SQL-Server-Versions-for-SharePoint-2019)
> - [**SQL Server Best Practices for SharePoint 2019**](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sql-server-best-practices-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is supported, as Article mentioned the minimum requirement and N-1 equitation between the SQL version not the updates.

> In order to maintain SharePoint and SQL Server compatibility we use the “SharePoint N-1 on SQL Server N+1”  equation to determine version support. Using SharePoint Server 2010 as an example, the N release of SQL Server is 2008/2008 R2 and N+1 is SQL Server 2012. For Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 the N release of SQL Server is 2012 and the N+1 is SQL Server 2014.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.14).aspx#section4

Yes you can go ahead and upgrade the SQL with Sp2 and complete you installation.

Comment: Hi @Waqas  based on your clarification should you tell me what this mean with SQL 2014 w/SP1 – n-1 ?? if we consider this a version so it means SharePoint 2016 can be installed on SQL 2012 with SP1 Right  ? is this what do you mean ? if right I think Microsoft mention it's not installed on SQL Server 2012 , meanwhile are you consider this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ronalg/2016/06/13/sharepoint-20132016-and-sql-server-2016-supportability-with-ssrs-fun-facts/ official link ,

Comment: No...N mean release of SQL version, so for SharePoint 16...N-1= 2016-1= 2014 and N+1 = will future version.....they link you are referring is SSRS.... read from here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.14).aspx#section4

Comment: Thanks Waqas for your reply , based on your link we agree on (N) is a version ? and based on my link you said it's for SSRS , so if I need to install SharePoint 2016 with SSRS I can't install it with SQL 2014 w/SP2 , Right ? because he mentioned only  (SQL 2014 w/SP1 – n-1)  so if we apply N as version that mean I can install SP 2016 with SQL 2012 SP1 !! but this version of SQL is not supported with SharePoint 2016 !!!! so whatever it's for SSRS or not , but in fact I can't install SharePoint 2016 with SQL Server 2012 SP1 !

Comment: Service pack not count towards the N equation....Version are SQL 2008, 2014, 2016, but not the updates/ service pack...if there is any requirement then MSFT tell that if a version with SP is required

Comment: No for sharepoint 2016, n is sql 2016 and n-1 will be 2014 not 2012

Comment: Great , although my attached link, is updated at 12/7/2016 that is the same date of launch SQL 2014 SP2 , but he didn't mention SP 2 in his update and consider (n-1) as  (SQL 2014 w/SP1 – n-1)  not as ((SQL 2014 w/SP2 – n-1) ) !   also consider this scenario : I have installed SP 2016 with SQL 2014 SP2 is this mean if I need to use SSRS it will not work untile uninstall SQL 2014 SP 2 , ! This is baffling :)

Comment: Another thing, sp are for fix within same release version not change version...what both articles mentioned min requirement...sql 2014 become supported after sp1...